# Python program Returning "None" as output

Tags: python

```
import random 

nums1 = [1,2,3]
nums2 = [random.shuffle(nums1)]
print nums2
```

how can I get nums2 as a list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

random.shuffle() returns `None`. So, you are getting a list with element `None`.

`random.shuffle()` shuffles a list in place. So print `nums1`.

However, if you want to have a new shuffled list, first do:

```
nums2 = nums1[:]
```

That will make a new copy of `nums1`

Then do:

```
random.shuffle(nums2)
print nums2
```